# "No operations allowed after connection closed " using Dart and Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, flutter, dart, spring-security

I am working with Spring Boot and Dart. When I hit the URL (using POSTMEN/Browser) to insert some data in MySql I got the response correctly. But WHen I send the 3 requests consecutively from Flutter Front-end using Dart language it most of the time returned the result of 2 GET request and through the error for the 3rd request and most of the time it works for all request.

Following is the `connection service` that I am using on backend to store the data.

**ConnectionService.java**

```
@Service
public class ConnectionService {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConnectionService.class);
    Connection connection = null;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    String datasourceUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/databaseName?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";

    public Connection createConnection() throws SQLException {


        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(datasourceUrl, "root", "root");
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
        return connection;
    }

    public void closeConnection() {
        try {
            connection.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

I am creating the object of the Connection service class and call the `createConnection()` to create the connection and `closeConnection()` to close that one.

**Controller.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    ConnectionService connectionService;


    @GetMapping(path = "/test")
    public void testFunction(@RequestParam(name = "abc") String abc) throws SQLException 
    {
        Connection connection = connectionService.createConnection();
        if (abc.isExist(param1,param2,connection)) 
        {
          //some code
            connectionService.closeConnection();

        } else
        {
            //some operation
              connectionService.closeConnection();
         }

    }
```

Guide me to resolve this issue.
Thanks

Comment: You have a multi-threaded application manipulating shared, global state (connection in ConnectionManager). One thread closes your single connection while another expects it to be still open. That's a classic race condition.

Comment: @Ralf What the solution than? sir please guide me in this regard.

Comment: I suggest you read up on the topics "concurrency", "multi-threading", "synchronization", and "thread-safety". Those are the general keywords your problem is related to. A web application is inherently concurrent/multi-threaded. So you need a fundamental understanding of what that means and what kind of programming model is required. A specific problem of your code  is that DB connections are not guaranteed to be thread-safe. It is best practice to pool those connections and hand them out  per request/thread. So another keyword to read up on would be "jdbc connection pool".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They problem is that instead of closing the instance `connection` that I have created  locally I am closing the main `connectionService` instance. This is the problem.

Now `connectionService.closeConnection();`
It should be `connection.closeConnection();`